Every even number is the sum of at most three primes
I'm failing to find online references to the following problem, which to me seems a slight weakening of the Goldbach conjecture.
Conjecture: every even integer $n$ is the sum of at most three primes.
In particular I don't understand why some answers online state this is equivalent to GC. Indeed if $n$ is the smallest counterexample to GC, then $n$ is surely the sum of three  primes (but not two), so the above conjecture could hold anyway.
Is there any reference to this problem?

When your are choosing the primes that sum to $~n,~$ are you allowed to sample with repetition?  That is, can a specific prime be used more than once as one of the terms used when summing to $~n~?$

The "every even integer $n$ is the sum of at most three primes" version is indeed weaker than the "every even integer $n$ is the sum of at most two primes"  Goldbach conjecture.  You could imagine that there might be exactly one large as-yet-unknown even number which is not the sum of two primes as a counterexample to the GC, so the number $2$ less is the sum of two primes; the GC counterexample is then the sum of three primes one of which is $2$.

However, "every even integer $n>4$ is the sum of exactly three primes" is equivalent to "every even integer $n>2$ is the sum of exactly two primes" as you have to use $2$ as the additional prime since all the other primes are odd.

You might also be interested in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65956/showing-the-equivalence-of-two-forms-of-the-goldbach-conjecture

Yes I confirm I wrote (and meant) at most three, not "exactly" three since this would clearly be equivalent to GC. So this statement is clearly weaker than GC but would make an elegant addendum to the (proven) weak GC since then it would imply that every integer (even or odd) is the sum of at most three primes: Is anybody here aware of any reference to this (partial results, attempts to prove etc...)?

This conjecture is equivalent to: for every even integer $n\ge4$, either $n$ or $n-2$ is the sum of two primes. This is related in some ways to the "exceptional set in Goldbach's conjecture" which there are some results on (by Montgomery & Vaughan, I believe).

This weaker version is almost surely open as well.

Interestingly it's proven for 4 primes (weak Goldbach for odd numbers, then add 3)

I thought this was already proven!  It's called Helfgott's theorem or something like that.

@HighAsAKiteOnMath Helfgott's theorem (former weak Goldbach conjecture) states that every odd integer greater than 5 can be written as the sum of exactly three primes. This trivially implies that every even integer greater than 8 can be written as the sum of at most 4 primes: if the number is odd, it's Helfgott, if it is even, subtract 3 and it becomes odd so it can be written as the sum of three primes, and for the original number you add 3 back. My question is if every integer (and due to Helfgott, we can restrict to even numbers) can be written as the sum of at most three primes.

@CryptoZiddy it is a conjecture yes.  It's just not stated anywhere.  I've conjectured things like the twin prime averages have at least two smaller twin prime averages as summands.  $a + b = c$.   I made a thread about it.  It can't really be proven easily, but I was thinking perhaps use this inductively in some kind of proof of the twin prime conjecture.  I've also come up with an exact counting formula of the twin prime averages in an interval, which is also not written anywhere for some STRANGE REASON!

@HighAsAKiteOnMath link?

Search my profile for twin-primes and certain key  words
